# How to use clip without zoom on background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem and need advice from more experienced developers.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="header-main" class="header container-fluid" style="background-image:url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/star_nebula_glow_94217_1920x1080.jpg');">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And CSS code:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height : 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju0uhc16/3/)

It is not visible in the JSFiddle, but I will try to explain.
I need to set the image as a background to fit all content inside this div and scale the image accordingly.

It works well, but because of `background-size:cover` it zooms the part of the image when screen size changes. Everything works perfectly except image quality on small screens but it becomes blurry for instance on iPhone 4.
So I wonder is there any way to clip part of image without zooming it, or how to save quality in this case. Maybe there are some best practices for such a task. (Like image set each for specific screen size).

Please suggest how to solve this problem or what are other possible ways to get a similar result?

Comment: But if your are using the `cover` attribute,then i think i can't be losing the quality of the image,and maybe you can try using `background-size: 100vw 100vh`?

Comment: use `contain` - It scales the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area